# Does it matter which way I order appositives?

Tags: word-order, appositives

Which is correct?

> A person sued BigCorp, the biggest company on Earth.
>
> A person sued the biggest company on Earth, BigCorp.

Are there any semantic differences between the 2 sentences? Is there a convention for putting appositives in the proper order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example uses a company that readers would probably know is the biggest, so I would put the subordinate clause last.

> A person sued BigCorp, the biggest company on Earth.

---

Suppose it is a not a well known company, the two options could be

> A person sued SmallCorp, a trading company.
>
> A person sued a trading company, SmallCorp.

where it seems clear that the first option is also better.

---

Now suppose it is a reasonably well known company, the two options are

> A person sued MiddleCorp, the trading company.
>
> A person sued the trading company MiddleCorp.

Here I would use the second example.

---

There is a similarity when talking about people:

> I met the actor Box Star Giant.
>
> I met New Lines Green, an actor.

I don't know if there is an actual rule, the right sentence seems to depend on its context.